# Import EML emails into Outlook 2010 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

Evening everyone. I'm helping setup a small office network, where a number of old PC's are being replaced with new ones with a 64-bit copy of Outlook 2010. The old emails were stored in Windows Live Email, and were exported as `.eml` files (since we were replacing the machines).

All the support I can find indicates that `.eml` files could simply be dragged-and-dropped into a folder in Outlook 2010, and it will import them correctly. However, it seems this is not the case in the 64-bit versioin, where dropping in `.eml` files results in a new message being created with these files as attachments.

We can re-download the most of the emails off the server if need be, but there were user folders which were not on the server which we were hoping to import.

Any advice would be fantastic at this point!

Comment: Spin up a copy of Outlook 32-bit, import the emails, export PST, import PST into Outlook 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

With Outlook (any version), you cannot import directly from an Outlook Express/Live mail file. It is funny, because if the account is set up, it will find that, and do it, but once you have removed the account, you can't directly.

You have a few choices:

1. If the PC's are still available, you can export the mail as a PST and re-import it as in the comment above.
2. If not, you can re-download it to a PST file on the computer, and if you are now using Exchange, again re-import it. If you are still using Internet mail, but just a new client, you can just use that PST directly (although see my second major caveat below). Major caveat: If you do this, make sure that "Download complete items including attachments" is selected. In my screenshot, it is grayed because I am on Exchange, but if you set up a POP/IMAP account you can set that. If you don't, especially with IMAP, items without bodies will blackhole. Second MAJOR caveat: If you are using IMAP, you will being importing to an IMAP PST, but you will also need to export to a different PST first. The reason is that in that first PST file, the locations of all the folders are not local, they are out on an IMAP server. Because of this, when that server is no longer available, again, things in the folders will disappear.
3. Buy a 3rd-party product like this one: http://www.outlookimport.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows live mail has the option to export folders within outlook2010 , I 've tried 32bit version and it worked perfectly